# Error attempting to launch Cloudsim

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am attempting to launch a basic CloudSim instance. I follow the tutorial here:
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/CloudSim/setup

But when I get to the following step (actually starting the instance), I get an error I cannot solve.
Specifically, I type:

./cloudsim-1.5.0/bin/create_cloudsim.py EMAIL ACCESSKEY SECRETKEY us-east-1a

Where EMAIL, ACCESSKEY, and SECRETKEY are my credentials, as appropriate. The output I get is the following: (my email replaced by EMAIL)

```
launch_db> c40e527fc/username = EMAIL 

launch_db> c40e527fc/constellation_name = c40e527fc 

launch_db> c40e527fc/gmt = 2013-05-29 20:35:08 

launch_db> c40e527fc/configuration = cloudsim 

launch_db> c40e527fc/constellation_directory = /tmp/tmph8ZJx1cloudsim 

launch_db> c40e527fc/constellation_state = launching 

launch_db> c40e527fc/error =  

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./cloudsim-1.5.0/bin/create_cloudsim.py", line 50, in 

    machine = cloudsim.cloudsim_bootstrap(username, tmp_fname.name, auto_launch_constellation)

  File "/home/modlabvis5/custom_worlds/cloudsim-1.5.0/cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 538, 

in cloudsim_bootstrap

    constellation_directory, website_distribution)

  File "/home/modlabvis5/custom_worlds/cloudsim-1.5.0/cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 245, 

in launch
    cfg = get_cloudsim_config()

  File "/home/modlabvis5/custom_worlds/cloudsim-

1.5.0/cloudsimd/launchers/launch_utils/launch_db.py", line 247, in get_cloudsim_config

    config = json.loads(s)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 328, in loads

    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode

    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I've got all the expected arguments: (email, both keys, and the zone), so I cannot determine what string might be missing. Really no idea what's going on here; any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3046/error-attempting-to-launch-cloudsim/) by [Nick Eckenstein](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/307/nick-eckenstein/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 59 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Those tutorials were created for using CloudSim with Amazon Web Services. The current version of CloudSim only works with SoftLayer cloud provider. If you are using CloudSim for the DARPA VRC, read the [VRC User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/CloudSim/VRCUserGuide) for detailed instructions of how to use the latest version of CloudSim with SoftLayer.

As Pedro suggested, 1.4.0 should work with Amazon.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Nick!. I had the same problem, and, how I solved it is installing cloudsim-1.4.0. For me seem to be that tutorials are wrong. Actually Amazon AWS had been changed by SoftLayer. I think that's the problem in CloudSim > 1.4. And as you can see what fails is a JSON decoding. What means that some kind of communication to host (SoftLayer whit amazon's credentials) had failed... Well but that last is just a theory. I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PedroMadrid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/378/pedromadrid/) with karma: 11 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1